# Getting error "PHP files in the Drupal files directory can be executed." in Security Review v.7.x-1.3

Tags: 7, security

I am on Drupal 7.92. When I run Security Review I get the error "PHP files in the Drupal files directory can be executed." in Security Review v.7.x-1.3. The sites/default/files directory is set to 770 apache:apache.

I run the following command in sites/default/files to find any PHP files:

```
find . -name "*.php"
```

It returns nothing. Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are the contents of the `.htaccess` file that is in the files directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security Review actually [places a PHP file in that directory](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/security_review/-/blob/7.x-1.x/security_review.inc#L630) and executes it, proving that PHP execution is possible. In addition Security Review checks for the existence and the contents of an `.htaccess` file in the files directory. On Apache web server a properly-configured `.htaccess` file there will prevent PHP execution.

So the most likely case is that `.htaccess` is missing or its contents are incorrect.